# Proper way to count number of string elements in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, count, segmentation-fault, sizeof

This is the code I'm blundering around with.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i=0;

    for(i=1;i<argc;i++){
        printf("arg %i: %s\n", i , argv[i]);
    }

    //custom array of strings
    char *states[] = {
                "California", "Oregon", "Idaho", "Arkansas", "Washington",
                "Texas", "Montana"
    };
    int num_states = sizeof(*states)-1;
    printf("%i\n", num_states);
    for(i=0;i<num_states;i++){
        printf("state %i: %s\n", i, states[i]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

My question is a fairly simple one, before I got this work I was encountering a very frustrating segfault.

"`int num_states = sizeof(*states)-1;`" this line works to return the number of string in array, minus one (not sure why the -1 is required to prevent segfault)

"`int num_states = sizeof(states);`" this returned 56, and caused my for loop to iterate through stuff that didn't exist.

The problem is I'm not sure what the difference is. My best guess is that the first line counts the total number of bytes that `states[]` is composed of, and that the second counts the number of locations in memory stored by `*states`.

Please correct me if my thinking is wrong. And if you can tell me why the -1 somehow prevented this segfault I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

#### The right way to do it

The value in `num_states` should be:

```
int num_states = sizeof(states) / sizeof(states[0]);
```

That is, the number of elements in an array is the size of the array divided by the size of the zeroth element of the array (which is the same size as every other element of the array).

This can be generalized to handle other arrays.  Harking back to Fortran and/or Basic, I often use a macro:

```
#define DIM(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))
```

Be careful: this only works with arrays where the size is known.  It does not work with 'arrays' passed to functions; such 'arrays' degenerate to pointers, and you end up with a wrong answer.  If you defined the function in the current source file (outside any function), or in the current function, you can use this safely.

#### Why your code worked

As to why your example worked — the answer is 'coincidence'.  It depends on the facts that:

- Your array has 7 elements.
- The size of a pointer is 8 bytes on your system.

The value of `sizeof(*states)` is 8 because `*states` is a `char *` and (on your 64-bit machine), the size of a pointer is 8.  Therefore `int num_states = sizeof(*states)-1;` 'works' by coincidence.  If you added or removed any entries from the array, or compiled the code on a 32-bit machine, then it would fail again (the exact modes of failure depending on the change in the environment), whereas computing the number of elements as shown would work correctly regardless of any of those changes.

Comment: This makes much more sense. However I am still left wondering why "sizeof(*states)-1" worked. In addition, I wonder if it possible for an array to have elements composed of an unequal number of bytes?

Comment: @Ajoe: The actual elements of an array are all the same size by definition.  However, if the elements are pointers, then the different pointers may point to objects of different sizes, as in your example where each element of `states` points to a null-terminated string of a different size.  The pointers are all the same size, but the objects pointed at are not.

Comment: Much appreciated, after further fumbling I found that my incorrect usage of that pointer did not allow my loop to increment past 8. Now I know.